# GSON deserialize json string without all fields

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java object with so so many fields...

```
 public class Foo {
        private String field0;
        private String field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;
        private String field4;
        private String field5;
        private String field6;
        private String field7;
        private String field8;
        private String field9;

        // Getters and Setters...

    }
```

And I have the following JSONString...

`{\"field0\": \"value0\", \"field1\": \"value1\"}`

I instantiate Gson with GsonBuilder() as follows...

```
        gson = new GsonBuilder()//
                .disableHtmlEscaping()//
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE) //
                .setPrettyPrinting()//
                .serializeNulls()//
                .setDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss [Z]")//
                .create();
```

And when i call `gson.fromJson(JSONString, Foo.class);` I got a new instance of Foo with all fields set as `null`. Even `field0` and `field1` that was specified in my JsonString...

How can I deserialize the JSONString above to get an instance with `field0` and `field1` set?

Comment: You set `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`, have you tried changing the JSON string to `{\"Field0\": \"value0\", \"Field1\": \"value1\"}`?

Comment: Thanks! Answer the question to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`, change the JSON string to `{\"Field0\": \"value0\", \"Field1\": \"value1\"}`.

Comment: I disagree here. JSON fields are most often written lower case as well, respectively using kepap-case (all-lower-case-with-dashes). Instead of using the artificial Uppercase field name, why not simply use lowerCase on both sides? And avoid that policy in the first place?!